# Is it possible to insert multiple rows in a table at once if there is another table below?

Tags: excel, vba

So in excel I've got a table and below that table is another table. If I select range from the last row of top table up to the next table, I can insert block of rows. But if the range goes over bottom table, I can't insert any rows. Why is that? Considering that bottom table gets shifted down anyways...
So is inserting rows one by one the only way or are there any other tricks. What is the fastest way? Using VBA is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I can think off is directly working on the table of interest like this:

```
Dim tb1 As ListObject, rowsToAdd As Long, i As Long

Set tb1 = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
rowsToAdd = 5 '// refers to the number of rows you want added //

With tb1
  For i = 1 To rowsToAdd
    .ListRows.Add
  Next
End With
```

> So is inserting rows one by one the only way...

I think yes, that is the only way. So in above example, I had to do a loop.